# How to remove latitude and longitude from Google Maps ACF field in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

In Wordpress, there's an Advanced Custom Fields Google Map option. I'm using that to refer to the address as text at one point. Code used:

```
<?php the_field('address');?>
```

Address is the custom variable for the Google Map.

This displays the street, city, state, zip code, country and latitude and longitude.

I don't need the country, lat or long. I've been trying to find an array I can edit, but no luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead of `the_field()` it will give you an array of 3 elements: *address*, *lat* and *lng*.

Unfortunately *address* is a string with the full address, country name included.
But if it's always the last voice separated by a comma, you can retrieve just the address string until the last comma, something like this:

```
$location = get_field('address');
if(isset($location['address'])) {
    $address = substr($location['address'], 0, strrpos($location['address'], ','));
    echo $address;
}
```

Comment: Good, I'm glad :). Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I just started here, so I didn't know of that option yet.